# DC-DC converter PCB Layout (TPS54202H )

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, grounding

In the datasheet for TPS54202H as an example the manufacturer recommends this layout.

1. What about the white area on the picture, is it necessary to pour it with ground? Top and bottom?
2. Where to place the terminals for GND-IN and GND-OUT wires?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to pour GND everywhere on the top layer, although there will be a large copper pour for GND.  Have a look at the TI's [evaluation board for TPS54202](http://www.ti.com/tool/tps54202hevm-716).

[image]

*p.s.* Когда мне нужно делать switcher, я стараюсь копировать разводку evaluation board "как можно ближе к тексту".